# How to connect a div to a data-url used in an iframe for searching a site

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

Is there a way that I can connect a div to a data-url that is also connected to a iframe. What I have sofar is the user makes a search in a search bar and it queries that search inside the iframes, what i'd like it to do is instead of the being able to move around in the website its self i'd like the user to be able to click on the iframe and it redirects there browser to the page queried in the iframe. I've attempted this by creating an invisible div that covers over the top of the iframe and there forth redirects them to the page inputted inside the div using the  variable but the a variable you cannot connect to a src or a data url Is there another variable I could use?

(Essentially i'm trying to do the same thing that I did with js and the iframe with the div)

Here is the HTML/JS code:

```
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">        

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
</head>

<body>

        <!--The Search bar as well-->
    <form onsubmit="return virtualSubmit(this)";>
        <input name="searchtext" type="text" />
        <input type="image" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20"/>
    </form>

    <div class="holder">
        <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250">
        </iframe>
        <div class="sampleDiv">
            <a class="invisibleDiv" href="http://www.google.com/custom?q="></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
        <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
            data-url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250">
        </iframe>
        <div class="sampleDiv">
            <a class="invisibleDiv" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
        <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://m.dictionary.com/definition"
            data-url="http://m.dictionary.com/definition/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250">
        </iframe>
        <div class="sampleDiv">
            <a class="invisibleDiv" href="http://m.dictionary.com/definition" data-url="http://m.dictionary.com/definition/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function virtualSubmit(form){
        var text = form.searchtext.value;
        var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
            items = targets.length;
        for(var i = 0; i<items; i++){
            var target = targets[i],
                url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
            target.href = url + text;
            target.src = url + text;
        }

        return false;
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
    body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #663300;
}

.holder {
    width: 400px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}

.frame{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sampleDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.invisibleDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to redirect the browser to a link clicked on in the iframe, use parent (the page object where your iframe is in)... so in your iframe code, you'd use something like that:

```
<a onclick="redirect()">click</a>
<script>
  function redirect() {
    this.parent.location="http://www.acme.org";
  }
</script>
```

ok, now i better understand what you try to achieve. I guess it is not possible as you have no control about the iframe contents. It already might have a target attribute on links etc. and you basically are planning to intercept or override that...

Comment: I'm trying to redirect them to the queried search in the iframe if you see the javascript it has it as the data-url so when the user searches something in my search bar it searches all of the websites in the iframe im trying to get it so redirect them to the searched site.